# Improper Integrals - infinity

Tags: calculus

The improper integral is defined as: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= \int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

And we also have $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

The integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\,\mathrm{d}x$ does not exist because $\int_{-\infty}^{a}x\,\mathrm{d}x$ does not exist.

But the integral $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} x\,\mathrm{d}x$ does exist since $\lim_{N \to \infty} [N^2/2 - N^2/2] = 0$

But can we not also define it as $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} x\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{a} x\,\mathrm{d}x+ \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{a}^{N} x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{a}x\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{a}^{\infty}x\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Now doesn't this make the LHS does not exist?

Comment: No, your first statement is only valid if both integrals exist.

Comment: In general, the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits only if both limits exist.  $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{a} x dx$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{a}^{N} xdx$ do not exist, as you mention.

Comment: So basically the middle part makes no sense in my last equation?

Comment: Yes. For example $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n-n) \neq  \lim_{n\to\infty} (n) - \lim_{n\to\infty} (n)$ because $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n)$ does not exist.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

The main reason not to define $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ as $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N}$ is that you'd expect:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+1)\;dx$$

Your definition, however, would not work. For example, under your definition, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\; dx = 0$$ but $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (x+1)\;dx=+\infty$$

The other problem with your definition is that the integral is defined often even if it is not true that $f(x)\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$.

*If* the integral exists by the usual definition, you get the same value with your definition, but there are lots of cases where the usual definition yields no value for the integral, but where your definition yields a value, and that value tends not to be useful very often.

Incidentally, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^N f(x)\;dx$ is called the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the improper integral.

Comment: I think you mean $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} x = 0$$, not $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\; dx = 0$$ which is the root of the problem. I can't differentiate the two.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming you define the integral that way, and showing how it yields oddities. Note, I say, "For example, under your definition..." before that statement.

Comment: Why aren't they the same then?

Comment: Why aren't what the same? $\int xdx$ and $\int (x+1)dx$? Because $\int_{-N}^{N} (x+1)dx = 2N$.

Comment: I was referring to the integarls in my first comment

Comment: Because $\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-N}^a xdx=-\infty$ and $\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_a^N xdx = +\infty$, and $-\infty + (+\infty)$ is undefined. So under the traditional definition of this indefinite integral, this would be undefined.

Comment: Then what is the meaning (and I don't mean just the equation) of $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} xdx$$ vs  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\; dx$$

Comment: The second one is defined in terms of two independent limits, the first is one limit. Because the two limits give $\pm\infty$, the result for the second one is undefined. The first one gives zero. How much more different do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Your third statement is incorect,
 $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} x$ does not exist.
And the reason is your last statement.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x = lim_{a\to\infty}lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{b} x$

your last statement is also a way to define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x$ and they both coreect 
and the integral does not Exist.

If you have to integrate  odd function between finite  symmetrical section your integral will be zero but in infinity section you cant know how your function will behave.

Comment: Of course it exists, it is zero, since $\int_{-N}^N  xdx = 0$.

Comment: Why do you say "If you have to integrate odd function between finite symmetrical section your integral will be zero but in infinity section you cant know how your function will behave."? Whatever you 'gain' while integrating from 0 to <some very large number> (+infinity), you'll 'lose' the same while integrating from <the same very large number with a negative sign) (-infinity) to zero.

Comment: but when $\N\to\infty\$ it is not the same N

Comment: $\int_{-N}^N x\,dx=0$ for all $N$, hence the limit is zero.